# Решение СЛУ с помощью метода Якоби

Tags: c

Задача заключается в том, чтобы найти приближенное решение с помощью метода Якоби, но программа выводит нули и не продолжает итерацию, не понимаю как исправить эту ошибку.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double diff(int n, double x1[n], double x2[n]) {
    double s = 0;
    int i;
        for( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            s += (x2[i]-x1[i]) * (x2[i]-x1[i]);
        }
        return s;
}
double jacobi(int n, double x1[n], double x2[n]) {
    int i, j;
    double s = 0, a[n][n], f[n];
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                s += x1[j]*a[i][j];
            }
            for(j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
                s += x1[j]*a[i][j];
            }
            x2[i] = (f[i] - s) / a[i][i];
        }
}
int main () {
    int n, i, j, k;
    double eps;
    printf ("Add N:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    printf ("Add epsilon:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &eps);
    double a[n][n], f[n], x1[n], x2[n];
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf ("%lf", &f[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            x2[i] = 0;
        }
        while(diff(n, x1, x2) > eps*eps) {
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                x1[i] = x2[i];
            }
            jacobi(n, x1, x2);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf ("%lf", x2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вводите матрицу в локальный массив `a[n][n]` в функции `main()`. Затем вызываете Вашу функцию `jacobi()`, в которой определен другой массив с именем a[n][n], который Вы и используете даже не проинициализировав. Поэтому и получаете нули (в этой последней матрице может быт любой мусор). Таким образом, даже если бы Вы сделали рабочую матрицу глобальным массивом, этот локальный в функции `jacobi()` с тем же именем всё портил. Вам нужно удалить этот последний массив, а рабочую матрицу нужно передавать параметром из функции `main()`. То есть нужно изменить: 1) удалить массив `a[n][n]` из функции `jacobi()`, 2) изменить заголовок этой функции, добавив в параметры массив `a[n][n]` и 3) исправить её вызов.

**UPD**: Программа не работает, потому что такая же ошибка была с вектором f[n] и еще одна ошибка - Вы не обнуляете заново сумму `s` для каждой строки матрицы (для каждого нового x2[i]).

И еще нужно главный цикл в `main()` (`while(diff(n, x1, x2) > eps*eps)`) сделать с пост-условием `do ... while()`, иначе Вы в него так и не зайдете.

После исправления ошибок, функция с методом Якоби должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
void jacobi(int n, double x1[n], double x2[n], double g[n], double m[n][n]) {
    double s = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            s=0;
            for(int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                s += x1[j]*m[i][j];
            }
            for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
                s += x1[j]*m[i][j];
            }
            x2[i] = (g[i] - s) / m[i][i];
        } 
}
```

Я эту функцию сделал бы более компактно:

```
void jacobi(int n, double x1[n], double x2[n], double g[n], double m[n][n]) 
{
    double row[n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        row[i] = g[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            row[i] -= (i != j) ? m[i][j] * x1[j] : 0.0;             
        x2[i] = row[i] / m[i][i];
    }
}
```

Проверил, вроде бы оба варианта работают верно. И не забывайте, что метод Якоби будет сходиться далеко не для каждой матрицы.

Comment: Исправил, все как вы и сказали, но программа по прежнему работает неправильно

Comment: @New_one, я же только написал, что не так с матрицей. Вы не просили полностью отладить код ;-).

Comment: @New_one, я дополнил ответ. Для некоторых матриц (это ограничение метода) работает правильно.